# Why is my Webpack bundle so large?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, webpack, momentjs

I am writing some JavaScript which uses [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Moment.js is supposed to be 30 KB gzipped and Handlebars is supposed to be less than 10 KB gzipped. But when I use Webpack to bundle my code, I get a resulting file which is 271 KB!

I installed webpack-bundle-size-analyzer to investigate and found much larger files than expected:

```
$ webpack --json | webpack-bundle-size-analyzer
moment: 454.54 KB (74.1%)
handlebars: 94.39 KB (15.4%)
twitter-text: 62.3 KB (10.2%)
<self>: 1.94 KB (0.317%)
```

I have a feeling I am doing something which is causing a lot of unnecessary things to be loaded since I was expecting a final file size <100 KB.

**main.js**

```
var template = require('./template.handlebars')
var Handlebars = require('handlebars/runtime')
var twitter = require('twitter-text')
var moment = require('moment')
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.min.js'
  },

  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.handlebars$/,
        loader: 'handlebars-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: are you configuring for prod or dev?

Comment: I saved quite a bit of space by switching from moment to date-fns. I can probably also save a bit of space by not using handlebars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update on Aug 10

You may refer to this [issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1435) on github/moment. Basically you can eliminate out all other locales which you don't need.

Extract from the comments:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\\\/]locale$/, /^\.\/(en|zh-tw)$/)
]
```

---

I think the webpack did its best already. When you look into the files in `node_modules/moment/min/`

You will see these:

```
220K  moment-with-locales.min.js
 57K  moment.min.js
```

So, if you include the moment with locales, 2XXKB is making sense. To further reduce the size, you may try

1. include the moment without locales explicitly

   ```
   var moment = require('moment/min/moment.min')
   // if you dun need the locale support
   ```
2. Or you can try to compress your output with gz manually with this plugin [compression-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/compression-webpack-plugin).

Comment: Actually, if you have access to the webserver, let say express, you can easily do the compression by adding `app.use(compression({ threshold: 0 }))`. This helps compress my js file from 600kb to 200kb. :D

Answer (score 1):

Add `IgnorePlugin` into `webpack.config.js` file and `import locale/xx` what you need.

Read more: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
  resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
  contextRegExp: /moment$/,
});
```